# Creating a development web server on Azure virtual machine with Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure

I want to move my development environment to Azure and I need to be able to debug as I would on a local machine so I'm thinking that an Azure virtual machine is the way to go. I would prefer not to have to install SQL Server on that VM (or to have a separate database server) so I'm wondering if I can point an Azure VM acting as a development web server running Visual Studio at an Azure SQL Database?

If anybody has experience of how best to set this up I would be grateful.

Comment: sure you can. I do that a lot. so what is your programming question ?!But this scenario is only supported for MSDN subscribers. If you do not have MSDN subscription, you cannot do that legally. If you have MSDN subscription, there are Gallery images with Visual Studio pre-installed and read to roll.

Comment: I'm asking if anybody has advice on how to set this up. For example, how do I configure it to minimise the latency between web server and database? Do I need to create a virtual / local network?

Comment: And exactly this type of questions are not suitable for StackOverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use SQL Express or LocalDB which ship with Visual Studio (depending on version), but nothing to stop you from using Azure SQL Database other than perhaps the [feature incompatibilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336281.aspx) it has with on-premises SQL Server - these will eventually be addressed but are present today.

If you have MSDN make sure to utilise your Azure credits (assuming you aren't using MSDN via an Enterprise Agreement).

Comment: Thanks Simon. LocalDB is by far the easiest option and gives me everything I need. My production DB is an Azure SQL database so I feel that I should be developing against that but maybe that's not necessary?

Comment: As long as you are aware of the differences (as I said, they are slowly disappearing) you'll be fine. There's a lot of apps deployed on Azure SQL DB so chances of you coming across something nobody has seen before is pretty slim.